# Tweepy support for premium/sandbox full history AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search_full_archive'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm having problems using tweepy to access historical content beyond the past 7 days using the new `search_full_archive` and `search_30_day` features. I've updated tweepy to Version: 3.9.0, yet still when I try to run either `api.search_full_archive` or `api.search_30_day` I get `AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search_full_archive'`

I will note that I am using the free sandbox versions and do have different environment names for my 30-days sandbox and my full-history sandbox.

Any thoughts?

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser(), wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

test = api.search_30_day(environment_name='30daycerb', q = '#cerb')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-0b2b236c134b> in <module>
----> 1 test = api.search_30_day(environment_name='30daycerb',
      2                                             q = '#cerb')

AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search_30_day'



my_new_tweets = api.search_full_archive(environment_name='cerbhistory', query='#CERB')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-c8e25af8d1ef> in <module>
----> 1 my_new_tweets = api.search_full_archive(environment_name='cerbhistory', query='#CERB')

AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search_full_archive'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem today. I was running my code on a [Deepnote](https://deepnote.com/) python notebook.

However after deleting tweepy package and manually installing latest from master on GitHub, I could solve the problem:

```
pip uninstall tweepy
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy@master
```

For some reason the [support for Premium API was not release in v3.9.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1175#issuecomment-659173030), but [merged later into master](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1294).

In my case, I also needed to restart the kernel of notebook, to finally fix the problem, but this is very specific probably.